# Weird Thread Situation -- Using a Thread only for Instantiating a Variable

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, events

I am using OpenCYC api (no too common, besides the point though), and I am trying to create an object `AccessObject` named `ao`. The problem is, for whatever reason, an `AccessObject` cannot be instantiated inside the main Java Swing Event Thread.

So as a workaround, I made another thread that just instantiates an `AccessObject` in it's `run()` method and also provides a getter for it to return it.

**So this is what I have for the calling code:**

```
// do something with code

AccessObject ao;
AccessObjectInstantiateThread aoThread = new AccessObjectInstantiationThread();
aoThread.start();

while(ao == null) // while loop to ensure we "wait" for aoThread to finish
{
     ao = aoThread.getAoObject();
}

// Then use ao however you want
```

Now this code works, but it seems pretty rediculous. Is there any better way to do this? Remember, there is no way I can instantiate an `AccessObject` under the main java event thread.

Thank you very much, Rich.

Comment: Don't freeze the UI thread.

Comment: If I don't "freeze" it with the `while` loop, then there is a chance (most likely) when I call `ao = aoThread.getAoObject()` that the value returned by `getAoObject()` could not be instantiated yet.

Comment: Why can't you instantiate it in the EDT? Either the instantiation is long, and you shouldn't wait for it to be instantiated in the EDT (because it'll freeze the GUI), or it's not long to create, and there's no reason not to instantiate it in the EDT. If it's long, the do the rest of the method once the object has been instantiated, without waiting in the EDT. I.e. have the other thread call the rest of the method.

Comment: We believe it is an error in the API. Our only option that remains is instantiating it in another thread.

Comment: "for whatever reason" really doesn't help us to know anything about *why* you can't initialize the object on the EDT. What happens when you try?

Comment: You can't make that statement that there is an error in the API, not until you can isolate the said error and show that it isn't an error in your logic or assumptions. My experience with my own code, when I've "found" API or Java errors, is that the latter is always true, that it is in fact an error of my logic or assumptions.

Comment: An error message is printed out saying unsucessful attempt at instantiating AccessObject in EDT. I have tried numerous things over the past few days and got nothing to work. But, when I use the exact same logic in a non-EDT thread it works great.

Comment: So assuming that I'd like to instantiate it in a different thread (as shown above) is there a nicer or better workaround?

Comment: 1) Instantiate it in a SwingWorker object, and check for a valid object before completing the `doInBackground()` method. 2) Add a PropertyChangeWorker to the SwingWorker that listens for SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE, then pass the object to your Swing program.

Comment: As a simple change to your above code, you could probably do an aoThread.join() instead of the while loop (which is slightly less ridiculous).  However, the answers below are likely a more correct method of handling your case.

Answer (score 4):

1. Instantiate it in a SwingWorker object, and check for a valid object before completing the `doInBackground()` method.
2. Add a PropertyChangeWorker to the SwingWorker that listens for SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE, then pass the object to your Swing program.

For example,

```
class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<AccessObject, Void> {
  public AccessObject doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // do whatever needed to create your AccessObject and check its completion

    // return your AccessObject
  }
}
```

In your Swing code:

```
final MySwingWorker mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker();

mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
  public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
    if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
      try {
        ao = mySwingWorker.get(); // ao is an AccessObject class field

        // you can use ao here

      }  catch (whaeverExceptionYouAreTrapping e) {
        // do something with exception
      }
    }
  }
});
mySwingWorker.execute();
```

Note, code note tested nor compiled.

---

**Edit** as per JB Nizet's recommendation you could also simply do an anonymous inner class in your Swing code and skip the PropertyChangeListener:

```
new SwingWorker<AccessObject, Void>() {
  public AccessObject doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // do whatever needed to create your AccessObject and check its completion

    // return your AccessObject
  }

  public void done() {
    try {
      ao = mySwingWorker.get(); // ao is an AccessObject class field

      // you can use ao here

    }  catch (whaeverExceptionYouAreTrapping e) {
      // do something with exception
    }
  }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Why not simply override `done()` and initialize the field from there?

Comment: @JBNizet: That can also be done if desired. Either way, `get()` must be called and the get() exceptions if any must be handled. I've been in the habit of using the PropertyChangeListener since it has worked better with my code's MVC structure.  If I have used done(), then the SwingWorker has to have more knowledge of the GUI and what it is doing with the created AccessObject. If I use the PCL, then the GUI itself does whatever it wants with the AccessObject, and the SW remains blissfully unaware.

Comment: I agree that your solution is better for a reusable SwingWorker. For a one-shot usage, using an inner class, simply delegating to a private method of the class in `done()` looks more straightforward to me. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may not work. You should at least declare your variable as follows:

**volatile** AccessObject ao;

The reason is, your EDT thread may cache the value of ao variable as an optimization and may not see ao is assigned to a new value.

I hope this code is at the beginning of you application and users will not see UI is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would create AccessObject `ao` on the start up thread (in the `main()` method) and not start your UI (`EventQueue.InvokeLater` with a runnable containing something like `new JFrame`) until after you had.

Failing that, make `ao` volatile.  Your instantiation code should set this value directly rather than bothering about a "get" method.  It should probably also call InvokeLater with a runnable to readjust the display--maybe enable a button or two and send the user a message that things are now possible that were not possible before.

Any code accessing `ao` has to be prepared for the fact that it may be null; your GUI has to work both ways, making its situation clear to the user.  Every check or reference should look something like:

```
final AccessObject  local_ao = ao;
if (local_ao != null)  {
    // Do things.  USE local_ao, NOT oa!!!
}
```

In short, always use local_ao, which won't change.  Remember that the value of `ao` can and will change at any time.  As you've described it, it will only change from null to non-null, and do so only once, but that may change as your code evolves.  (If it won't evolve, my first suggestion might be best.)

Your UI (EventQueue) code should not wait for anything.  Threads are pain, and I'd take a little delay in the UI over using a thread any day.  But you've already paid the price for a thread, so you may as well get your money's worth.